# Finding a combined function from infinite series with a function in it

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation, generating-functions, summation-method

If I know:$$y(z(x))=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {4nz(x)^{4n}}{(4n)!}$$and$$y(0)=z(0)=0$$how can I find $y^{-1}(z(x))$?

Comment: It might be worth looking into the Lagrange inversion formula

Comment: If $y(z)=\sum_{n=1}\frac{nz^n}{(4n)!}$, then $y(z)=\frac12\sqrt[4]{z}\left( \sinh(\sqrt[4]{z})-\sin(\sqrt[4]{z})\right)$.  Can you find the inverse function $y^{-1}(z)$ in explicit form?

Comment: @MarkViola but this is just not the same thing...

Comment: How is it not the "same thing?"